# How to edit build path entries in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-appcompat, buildpath

So I have been having trouble with the Android Support Library with respect to a Jar mismatch or the like where for some reason I was having trouble extending the `ActionBarActivity` as it was giving the error that appcompat_v7.apk could not be found.

Hence I deleted the original library I had in my Eclipse projects and reinstalled the Support Library, attaching it to my project of interest with [these instructions](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html). Note that following these instructions, the new project folder is now "android-support-v7-appcompat" rather than the original "appcompat_v7".

Following this, I have tried several times to clean my project, quit and reenter Eclipse, but I still come up with two problems stating: "The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved" and "'ProjectName' is missing required Java project: 'appcompat_v7'".

However, when going to Project --> Properties --> Java Build Path, under "Order and Export" a folder named "appcompat_v7" is shown as missing, though the other jars of interest are present, as can be seen in this screenshot:

[image: appcompat_v7 is shown as missing]

What can I do to delete or edit this build path entry? To be clear, at this point my project will not even compile, although prior to my deleting the original appcompat_v7 folder it was able to compile but not load any `Activity` that extended the `ActionBarActivity`. I would love to be able to compile my code again -_-

Comment: Go to the "Libraries" tab.

Comment: Would you like me to include an image of that tab as well?

Comment: The problem is, underneath that tab, there is no "appcompat_v7" library listed, just the jars that are of relevance (v4 & v7)

Comment: What about the "Projects" tab?

Comment: Ohhhh my goodness, it was there. I can't believe I didn't look before. I deleted the project (appcompat_v7) from that tab and now my app seems to compile. Thank you so much!

Comment: Now that I notice, the folder icon next to "appcompat_v7" indicates that it is a project.

Comment: Duly noted, thanks! If you write up an answer for this question I can accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The folder icon next to "appcompat_v7" indicates that it is a project. You should remove it from the "Projects" tab.